# BOOST ASIO: Why don't I get "bind: Address already in use" in Windows (but do get it in Linux)?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Trying to bind an already bound TCP port should raise exception ("bind: Address already in use" exception).

It does happen under Linux. But under Windows , no exception is raised..

Could it be because under windows it tries to bind to ANY interface? but in Linux it tries to bind to ALL of them and raise an exception if not all of them are bound ?

Here is the code snippet:

```
    try {
        tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8081);
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service);
        acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
        acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::enable_connection_aborted(true));
        acceptor.bind(endpoint);
        acceptor.listen(1024)
    catch(std::exception &e) {
         cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows, the option `tcp::acceptor::reuse_address` is equivalent to calling `setsockopt` and specifying `SO_REUSEADDR`.  This specifically allows multiple sockets to be bound to an address even if it is in use.  See the MSDN documentation [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There's a corresponding option in Win32 (`SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`) which is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740618).  This post details some potential drawbacks with simply using `SO_REUSEADDR` on Win32 platforms.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it. Alas, I can't find in ASiO a corrosponding SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE flag.. So I guess the only option would be to include winsock.h and set this flag direclty..

Comment: Yes there are a couple of featuers in boost::asio that I have found lacking, this is one, the other is IGMPv3 multicast support.  In both cases you have to use the native socket and the `setsockopt` function.

Comment: Kind of late but you can do:
`typedef boost::asio::detail::socket_option::boolean<BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF(SOL_SOCKET), SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE> excluse_address;

acceptor.set_option(excluse_address(true));`