# Boost ASIO Linux gets Address already in use despite reuse_address option, why?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio, asio

```
MyClass()
: m_IoService()
 , m_Acceptor(m_IoService)
{
    char address[] = "0.0.0.0";
    char port[] = "6400";
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(m_IoService);
    boost::system::error_code resultCode;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve({ address, port }, resultCode);
    if (resultCode)
    {
    }

    m_Acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol(), resultcode);
    if(resultCode)
    {
    }

    m_Acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true), resultCode);
    if (resultCode)
    {
    }

    m_Acceptor.bind(endpoint, resultCode);
    if (resultCode)
    {
        // Error here
    }
}
```

I have an error coming out of acceptor.bind on Linux for `Address already in use` but I clearly have `reuse_address(true)` set. This does not occur on Windows. Am I missing another option?

Note that this does not happen all the time, but sometimes. I presume it happens when the last process/run of the program shutsdown, the port goes into the WAIT state, and then if this program runs again in that timespam, it can't reuse the port as I'd like it to. But if enough time passes, or the port is closed securely, it's not a problem. Windows, however, never has this issue.

This SO seems to indicate there is a difference between the platforms, but it does not explain how to get Linux to reuse the port: [BOOST ASIO: Why don't I get "bind: Address already in use" in Windows (but do get it in Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164879/boost-asio-why-dont-i-get-bind-address-already-in-use-in-windows-but-do-ge)

Comment: I completed the constructor method for you, apologies.
This is basic boost::asio code, nothing more is necessary than this to repro.

For a complete compile example you could use this: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/http/server/server.cpp

Comment: "I presume it happens when the last process/run of the program shutsdown, the port goes into the WAIT state". You can run `ss -ant` to see if the socket is in `WAIT` state.

Comment: I compile the examples in http directory, run it and stop. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the error. I am running fedora linux 30 with asio master branch from git repo.

Comment: When I first asked, I thought it was always occurring but after extended use, it only occurs seldom. Say I have hundreds of processes starting and stopping that execute this and lock to this port on a bunch of different Linux machines, I'd say it occurs in 1 / 100 times it seems. Because the repro rate is so low, I don't have access to the machines at the exact time the issue occurs to run the command. It's curious that it happens at all. Wonder if its just timing, and if spinlocking a few seconds after failing to bind the port then retrying would work.